# Connecting to a node.js/Socket.io server from WebOS

Tags: node.js, webos, socket.io

I'm a new developer to WebOS. I am trying to create a pretty basic node.js server to connect with via Socket.io from WebOS. I have the server up and running no difficulty. The problem comes in when I try to connect to it from the WebOS device.

The node.js script is operating using Socket.io to handle the connections. I run the commands per Socket.io to connect to the server:

(Socket is explicitly called in the head.)

Code:

```
var socket = new io.Socket('192.168.1.2', {port:4000});

socket.connect();
console.log('connecting...');
socket.on('connect', function() {
});
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    var data = message.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&    lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
                  ...
});
```

All I get on the app is a blank white screen. Once I comment out the socket.connect() it loads properly, but obviously doesn't connect.

Is there a problem using sockets like this on WebOS?

Oh, the socket absolutely DOES connect. I can receive data from it and see it in the logs, it just kills the UI for some reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Where are you using the node.js code? Node.js support comes in version 2+ of the WebOS SDK and then you have to structure your WebOS app a bit differently. The node.js code isn't mixed in with the app code, it's stored separately and then used like you would use a built-in WebOS service.

Try the BasicService example app from the SDK as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use the node.js API from within a webOS application. That's not going to work. The webOS app environment is browser-based, so you'd want to use XMLHttpRequest, or the Prototype library's Ajax object.